# Do Until IsEmpty Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code written.  I am trying to change a series of cells that have a date format over to a label format.  I can get the Application.SendKeys to work outside of this Macro.  I can get the macro to work other commands.  Gotta be something simple I'm doing wrong but I cant figure it out. Not super VBA experienced.

```
Sub Step2()

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    Application.SendKeys ("{F2}")
    Application.SendKeys ("{Home}")
    Application.SendKeys ("{'}")
    Application.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Send Keys are not the best way to do things, as it depends on the focus.

Instead just do what you want in code:

```
Sub Step2()
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Selection
    rng = "'" & rng.Text
Next rng
End Sub
```

This will append each cell that is selected, with `'` in front of the displayed text.